# How to fetch files from remote systems through SSH in Active choice parameters Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to fetch the files from remote systems and display in drop down box. I am using Active choice parameter with groovy script, but not able to connect to SSH and fetch remote files

Below script I have executed in the active choice parameter

```
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
def proc = "sshpass -p 'password' ssh -p 22 username@hostname ls -l".execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
return sout.tokenize()
```

Comment: What is your question?  Do you get errors? Also never use String.execute() - use Array.execute() instead.  With a string groovy will just split on whitespaces; also `'` is wrong - you dont need to quote for a shell that is never involved. If your password contains whitespaces, this and the `'` are your problem. Use `["sshpass", "-p", "password", ...].execute()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A more robust way would be to use a (Java) Library that handles SSH such as JSCH (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) like so:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession("$username","$host", 22);
session.setPassword("password");

// Avoid asking for key confirmation 
// depends on your needs but given your use case it might be a good idea
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(prop);

session.connect();

ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
channelssh.setCommand("ls -l"); // restore date
channelssh.connect();

InputStream is=channel.getInputStream();
is.eachLine {
    println(it)
}
channelssh.disconnect();
```

Comment: how this java code is relevant to Jenkins?